# How to combine list elements into pairs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a convenient function in javascript, with or without underscore.js, that takes a list of the form `[a, b, c, d]` and transforms it into a list of the form `[[a, b], [b, c], [c, d]]`?

Comment: If this is a question about code, please post your code. Otherwise, asking for libraries is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily solved with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var makePairs = function(arr) {
    // we want to pair up every element with the next one
    return arr.map(function(current, i, arr) {
        // so return an array of the current element and the next
        return [current, arr[i + 1]]
    }).slice(0, -1)
    // for every element except the last, since `arr[i + 1]` is `undefined`
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
// you should never use `document.write`, except for in stack snippets
document.write(makePairs(arr).join("<br>"));
```

Comment: javascripts interpretation of "map" amazes me. Thank you.

Comment: @wirrbel it's one of my favorite functions—it's just so darn useful

Comment: I think I never saw an implementation of `map` that passes an index to the lambda

Comment: @wirrbel the anonymous function passed to map can take up to three arguments: the current element, the index, and the array being operated on

Answer (score 1):

The trivial functional-programming approach would be to use some underscore helper functions:

```
function consecutives(arr) {
    return _.zip(_.initial(arr), _.rest(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

However, it's really easy to write your own function.  Here's one that is faster (and, I believe, easier to read/understand) than the map-based solution proposed by royhowie:

```js
function pairNeighbors(arr) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArray.push([arr[i - 1], arr[i]]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(pairNeighbors([1, 2, 3, 4])));
```